# Python server sent event inconsistent messages received by the client

Tags: python, flask, server-sent-events, event-stream

I'm currently having issues regarding delayed response using text/event-stream in python3.

The issue I'm encountering was message **inconsistencies**. Messages sent from the server aren't always get received by the client.

I'm using POSTMAN to send a test data to the server by sending consecutive messages. Sometimes the client receives the messages I sent, then after a while like a few seconds of pause the client will no longer receives anything that I sent, then after a short while it will start to receive again.

here is the sample code I'm currently using.

**sse.py**

```
from typing import Iterator
import random
import string

from collections import deque
from flask import Response, request
from gevent.queue import Queue
import gevent

def generate_id(size=6, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


class ServerSentEvent(object):
    """Class to handle server-sent events."""
    def __init__(self, data, event):
        self.data = data
        self.event = event
        self.event_id = generate_id(),
        self.retry = 5000
        self.desc_map = {
            self.data: "data",
            self.event: "event",
            self.event_id: "id",
            self.retry: 5000
        }

    def encode(self) -> str:
        """Encodes events as a string."""
        if not self.data:
            return ""
        lines = ["{}: {}".format(name, key)
                 for key, name in self.desc_map.items() if key]

        return "{}\n\n".format("\n".join(lines))


class Channel(object):
    def __init__(self, history_size=32):
        self.subscriptions = []
        self.history = deque(maxlen=history_size)
        self.history.append(ServerSentEvent('start_of_history', None))

    def notify(self, message):
        """Notify all subscribers with message."""
        for sub in self.subscriptions[:]:
            sub.put(message)

    def event_generator(self, last_id) -> Iterator[ServerSentEvent]:
        """Yields encoded ServerSentEvents."""
        q = Queue()
        self._add_history(q, last_id)
        self.subscriptions.append(q)
        try:
            while True:
                yield q.get()
        except GeneratorExit:
            self.subscriptions.remove(q)

    def subscribe(self):
        def gen(last_id) -> Iterator[str]:
            for sse in self.event_generator(last_id):
                yield sse.encode()
        return Response(
            gen(request.headers.get('Last-Event-ID')),
            mimetype="text/event-stream",
            headers={
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                "Connection": "keep-alive",
                "Content-Type": "text/event-stream"
            })

    def _add_history(self, q, last_id):
        add = False
        for sse in self.history:
            if add:
                q.put(sse)
            if sse.event_id == last_id:
                add = True

    def publish(self, message, event=None):
        sse = ServerSentEvent(str(message), event)
        self.history.append(sse)
        gevent.spawn(self.notify, sse)

    def get_last_id(self) -> str:
        return self.history[-1].event_id
```

**service.py**

```
import json
import os

import requests
from app.controllers.sse import Channel
from flask import send_file, \
    jsonify, request, Blueprint, Response
from typing import Iterator

blueprint = Blueprint(__name__, __name__, url_prefix='')
flask_channel = Channel()

@blueprint.route("/stream")
def stream():
    return flask_channel.subscribe()


@blueprint.route('/sample/create', methods=['GET'])
def sample_create():
    branch_id = request.args.get('branch_id', None)
    params = request.get_json()
    if not params:
        params = {
            'id': 'sample_id',
            'description': 'sample_description'
        }
    flask_channel.publish(json.dumps(params), event=branch_id)
    return jsonify({'success': True}), 200
```

I'm wondering if there's a better solution for this. I'd appreciate any help or ideas.

Comment: I'd recommend you to split your questions into separate posts because they aren't connected. I'm sure that after that you'll get solutions faster. Also, it'll be better to have more information about your deployment (configuration files and so on).

Comment: As mentioned by the other community support member, you might need to provide some extra details on how exactly you are deploying the flask on GKE ie your second concern? Were you following any documentation? Creating a new thread with all those information will be a good idea. That's being said, you can also to refer [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/a-guide-to-deploy-flask-app-on-google-kubernetes-engine-bfbbee5c6fb) guide to deploy flask app on GKE, just to make sure that you didn't miss anything?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will separate the question instead.